# Почему-то не передается переменная при использовании FSMContext

Tags: python, aiogram

Пытаюсь передать переменную с помощью хранилища машины состояний. Но на мое удивление она не передается. Вообще ничего не передается. Будто вторая функция совершенно не работает, ведь даже сообщения с обычным текстом он не отправляет. Может быть я слепой конечно и не вижу каких-то очевидных вещей. Буду рад вашей помощи!)

```
@dp.message_handler(state=GameCheck.name)
async def from_name_to_id(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['name'] = message.text
        name_game = data.get('name')
    try:
        game_id_value = check_id(f'{name_game}')
        await GameCheck.name_id.set()
        await state.update_data(game_id=game_id_value)
    except UnboundLocalError:
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text='Убедитесь в правильности написания названия вашей игры, '
                                                          'ведь по нашим данным, такой игры нет в Steam.')
        await state.finish()


@dp.message_handler(state=GameCheck.name_id)
async def id2_handler(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        game_id = data['game_id']
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text=game_id)
```

P.S. Я удостоверился в том, что функция `id2_handler` не срабатывает. Попытался сделать вывод в терминал, когда дело доходит до нее, но ничего. Прилагаю место, где регистрирую состояния

```
class GameCheck(StatesGroup):
    name = State()
    id = State()
    name_id = State()
    base = State()
```

Так же в дополнении в `check_id(f'{name_game}')` возвращается число типа `integer`, но к решению вопроса это не относится уже.
Жду ваших предложений!

Comment: а вы проверяли, в `check_id(f'{name_game}')` что-нибудь возвращается? Потому, что если `game_id_value` присвоить значение, то оно прокидывается далее

Comment: @ZxNuClear конечно проверял, даже скажу больше, делал это не раз. возвращается число типа integer

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй вместо

```
async with state.proxy() as data:
    game_id = data['game_id']
```

использовать

```
data = await state.get_data()
game_id = data["game_id"]
```

UPD: И в функции `from_name_to_id` пропиши
`await GameCheck.name_id.set()` после
`await state.update_data(game_id=game_id_value)`

Comment: В дополнении было описано, что функция `id2_handler` почему-то не срабатывает, т.е. проблема уже не в передаче переменной, как было изначально. А так же, уже пробовал использовать `state.get_data`, ничего не менялось. И место где я задаю состояние тоже уже менялось, от этого ничего не зависит по моим опытам.

Comment: Тогда ищи ошибку в другом месте, потому что тут все правильно

Comment: уже в течении месяца пробую разные вещи, ничего не помогает. Я согласен, что здесь все верно, но почему-то не работает. Я в смятении

Comment: Если хочешь можешь оставить больше кода, также где ты регистрируешь хендлеры, может смогу помочь

Comment: как приеду домой - добавлю больше кода, тогда отмечу вас в комментарии